# Deleting Circular Import Python

Tags: python, circular-dependency

I recently downloaded a module called 'nilearn', but accidentally downloaded it onto my Desktop directory. Now whenever I use it I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'nilearn' has no attribute 'image' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I have tried uninstalling it with:

```
pip3 uninstall nilearn
```

And it says that it has been uninstalled, yet I receive the same error. Could somebody explain how to uninstall the module? Thanks.

Comment: you said you downloaded it to your desktop directory... Have you deleted it there too?

Comment: Every time i delete it it re-appears @Sadap